# What is this cluster?

Tags: raspberries

OK, so I was gifted with an everbearing raspberry vine. I noticed this on the top of one of my healthy primocanes (I say healthy because I had to prune an unhealthy cane recently). I cannot tell if this is leaves or if it may be putting out some raspberries, or something else. You may have to look closely. Look where my fingers are; some "nodules" are above them and they appear to be in a cluster. They are very tiny right now. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you[image: ![my everbearing raspberry is up to something]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94RNI.jpg)

Comment: I think it is normal (e.g. on my raspberries), but I see no references online. In any case it is only on first year sprout, right? Could be the buds of thorns.

Comment: It is a first year sprout, but it's heritage everbearing. I read somewhere that everbearing raspberries COULD...big could...produce fruit in the fall after they are planted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I have done some research and I found that it is producing blooms...and then if things go well it should produce raspberries!